# Laravel Log the Full URL of HTTP Request / Response

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
    
    
$url = 'http://example/';
$data = { name: 'quan'};
$http = Http::withHeaders([
    'x-id' => 1,
]);
    
$response = $http->post($url, $data);
```

Hi all, want to ask in Laravel can I log the http request / response with full url? like

```
'http:example?name=quan'
```

something like this.

the guzzle http version used is 7.2

I try this method

```
$response->getEffectiveUrl();
```

but it seems like cannot. Anyone have a greate idea to help me log out the url? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
final class LogMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    private $logger;

public function __construct(
        Logger $logger,
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $this->logger->info('Dump request', [
            'request' => serialize($request),
            'response' => serialize($response),
        ]);
                
        return $response;
    }
}
```

this is what i found,
docs: https://lessthan12ms.com/how-to-log-every-http-request-and-response-in-laravel.html